# Get the path of a closed folder with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm looking for a solution to get with Applescript the path of a folder closed by a user. The aim is to call another scripts with this path in argument.

I already tried to to this, but it seem to not work (my Folder actions are correctly set):

```
on closing folder window for theAttachedFolder
tell application "Finder"

    set thePath to POSIX path of theAttachedFolder
    display dialog thePath

    end tell
end on closing folder window for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `end on closing folder window for` to `end closing folder window for`, because this block starts with the word `on` and ends with the word `end`. In both cases, next to it you must write the name of the action, in this case: `closing folder window`.
Additionaly, you can move `display dialog` out of the tell block, because it's not necessary to target the Finder application. `display dialog` is part of Standard Additions.

Code:

```
on closing folder window for theAttachedFolder
    tell application "Finder"

        set thePath to POSIX path of theAttachedFolder

    end tell
    display dialog thePath
end closing folder window for
```